# Convert SQL value from 000000 to 00:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Everyone I'm just a newbie in SQL.

I have a column which displayed Start Time 042000 and End time 050000. The field name is `starttme` char(8). What I want to do is to format the displayed value from `042000` to `04:20:00`.

This is what I've tried so far, and it is not working.

```
select convert(char(8), starttme,101) as Start Time
from sampletable
```

And this is how I display it in gridview

**VB**

```
 Protected Sub loadgrid()
    For Each dt As System.Data.DataTable In prod2()
        Dim i As Integer = i + 1
        Dim dv As New System.Data.DataView(dt)
        Dim dt2 As System.Data.DataTable = dv.ToTable(False, {"Start Time", "End Time"})

        Select Case i
            Case 1

                GridView1.DataSource = dt2
                GridView1.DataBind()

             Case 2 -- codes here --
             Case 3 -- codes here --


        End Select
    Next



End Sub
```

FrontEnd

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class = "grd"  runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Format in the UI, not in the database.

Comment: Don't store date/time in varchar columns, use proper data types!

Comment: @DavidG wrong, if it meant to be a time value, store it as a time value.

Comment: 114 is the correct time style, not 101

Comment: @Pred Regardless of that, the formatting should still happen in the UI.

Comment: @DavidG True, however storing date/time values as string is way worse, than formatting them in sql.

Comment: @DavidG care to share some sample? I still don't know how to format it in UI. Thank you.

Comment: UI stands for 'User Interface' it's what you're using to actually present the data to customers. This could be SSRS, Excel etc there's a number of options for this, it all depends upon what you're using.

Comment: @Pred Yes, so I'm not wrong am I?

Comment: @x'tian How could we possibly suggest how to format your UI if we don't know how things are being presented?

Comment: @DavidG Hi I have edited my codes above. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the output in SQL Management Studio, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(col, 4, 0, ':'), 2, 0, ':')
FROM ...
```

However, formatting should be done closer to the layer where you display the value, e.g in the UI layer, if your system has one, in the layer that produces the output file, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF('042000', 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')
```

this will output :

```
04:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 101 which is a date style with no time element.

You need to use 114 for what you want.

```
Select convert(char(8),starttme,114) as [Start Time] from sampletable
```

For example, this gives the current time:

```
select convert(char(8),getdate(),114) as [Current Time]
```

Other formatting styles can be seen here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if the time is always 6 digits you can do it like this:

```
select SUBSTRING (starttme, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING (starttme, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING (starttme, 5, 2)
```

Comment: What if I want it to display 4 digits only? How do I remove the last two digits? And Is it possible to add AM/PM? Thanks.

Comment: You can do whatever you want!
    select SUBSTRING (starttme, 1, 2)  This code means : Take starttme and give me from character 1 and for 2 (if starttme is 123456 then gives you back 12) In the end you can just add .... + 'AM' or 'PM'

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
select STUFF(STUFF( '042000', 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as [Start Time]
from sampletable
```